# Count in Linq query with multiple join EF

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, linq

Hi Helpies I am new to EF and linq queries

```
        var chatEntryDetails = await
            (
                from chatEntry in dbChatEntry
                where chatEntry.ChatId == chat.Id
                join groupMembers in dbGroupMember on chatEntry.GroupMemberId equals groupMembers.Id
                join user in dbUser on groupMembers.UserId equals user.Id
                join countChatEntryUserStatus in dbChatEntryUserStatus.Where(e => e.DateReadByUser != null).Count() on chatEntry.Id equals countChatEntryUserStatus.ChatEntryId
                join chatEntryUserStatus in dbChatEntryUserStatus.Where(e => e.GroupMemberId == groupMemberId) on chatEntry.Id equals chatEntryUserStatus.ChatEntryId into ce
                from chatEntryUserStatus in ce.DefaultIfEmpty()
                orderby chatEntry.CreateDateTime descending
                select new ChatEntryDetails
                {
                    UserId = user.Id, GreetingName = user.GreetingName, GroupMemberId = chatEntry.GroupMemberId,
                    CreateDateTime = chatEntry.CreateDateTime, Details = chatEntry.Details, ChatType = ToApi(chatEntry.ChatType),
                    DateReadByUser = chatEntryUserStatus.DateReadByUser, ChatEntryId = chatEntry.Id, ReadByCount = countChatEntryUserStatus
                }
            )
            .PerPage(page, perPage)
            .ToListAsync();
```

When Executing this I got the following error

```
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'IQueryable<<anonymous type: <anonymous type: <anonymous type: <anonymous type: ChatEntryDb chatEntry, GroupMemberDb groupMembers> <>h__TransparentIdentifier0, UserDb user> <>h__TransparentIdentifier1, IEnumerable<ChatEntryUserStatusDb> ce> <>h__TransparentIdentifier2, ChatEntryUserStatusDb chatEntryUserStatus>>'.  'Join' not found. [UserServerApiLib]
```

Everything works fine without this line

```
join countChatEntryUserStatus in dbChatEntryUserStatus.Where(e => e.DateReadByUser != null).Count() on chatEntry.Id equals countChatEntryUserStatus.ChatEntryId
```

Here I want the count chatEntryUserStatus where DateReadByUser is not null
This line is supposed to get the count from chatEntryUserStatus table with few conditions there is one table chatEntry and they related as chatEntry.id = chatEntryUserStatus.ChatEntryId and for every chatEntry it has multiple records in chatEntryUserStatus so I want that count from chatEntryUserStatus for every chatEntry

**If not count then If I can get all the chatEntryUserStatus records for every chatEntry**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you joining instead of using navigation properties ?

Comment: Can you explain how can i do that?

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `join countChatEntryUserStatus in dbChatEntryUserStatus.Where(e => e.DateReadByUser != null).Count() on chatEntry.Id equals countChatEntryUserStatus.ChatEntryId`. A count should be equal to `ChatEntryId`?

Comment: This line is supposed to get the count from chatEntryUserStatus table with few conditions
there is one table chatEntry and they related as chatEntry.id = chatEntryUserStatus.ChatEntryId and for every chatEntry it has multiple records in chatEntryUserStatus so I want that count from chatEntryUserStatus for every chatEntry

Comment: @GertArnold do you need see the schema?

Comment: I don't think that's legal... You can't expect to join a Count to a key on another entity...What you really need to read up on is establishing the relationships between the entities using Navigation Properties, then from there composing a projection for the details you want to load including filtered related data and things like counts. Trying do do that with the linq QL (from..where..join) makes that 50x harder to piece together.

Comment: @StevePy can you explain how can i do that?

Comment: If not count then If I can get all the chatEntryUserStatus records for every chatEntry

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Comment: @GertArnold can you convert this using relationship?

Comment: The message is: first create a decent class model, adhering to best practices for working with EF, which includes creating navigation properties. That's your job. We can't do it for you. If you run into an issue while doing that you may ask a *new* question on that specific issue but not before you did your due diligence.

Comment: In many cases the object models new developers on a project are working on already have navigation properties, they just don't know how to leverage them. For a start, does your dbChatEntry entity have a collection of dbGroupMember defined? This commonly is declared as something like `public virtual ICollection<dbGroupMember> GroupMembers {get; set; }` or maybe `public virtual List<dbGroupMember> ...` If something like that exists in your class, the navigation property is there. If not, that is the kind of thing you need to understand and implement to begin with.

Comment: Yes navigation properties are there @StevePy as I said I am a newbie to EF.
And all the object models are well defined

Answer (score 0):

Based on

> Yes navigation properties are there

and looking at this Linq statement:

```
var chatEntryDetails = await
(
    from chatEntry in dbChatEntry
    where chatEntry.ChatId == chat.Id
    join groupMembers in dbGroupMember on chatEntry.GroupMemberId equals groupMembers.Id
    join user in dbUser on groupMembers.UserId equals user.Id
    join countChatEntryUserStatus in dbChatEntryUserStatus.Where(e => e.DateReadByUser != null).Count() on chatEntry.Id equals countChatEntryUserStatus.ChatEntryId
    join chatEntryUserStatus in dbChatEntryUserStatus.Where(e => e.GroupMemberId == groupMemberId) on chatEntry.Id equals chatEntryUserStatus.ChatEntryId into ce
    from chatEntryUserStatus in ce.DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby chatEntry.CreateDateTime descending
    select new ChatEntryDetails
    {
        UserId = user.Id, 
        GreetingName = user.GreetingName, 
        GroupMemberId = chatEntry.GroupMemberId,
        CreateDateTime = chatEntry.CreateDateTime, 
        Details = chatEntry.Details, 
        ChatType = ToApi(chatEntry.ChatType),
        DateReadByUser = chatEntryUserStatus.DateReadByUser, 
        ChatEntryId = chatEntry.Id, 
        ReadByCount = countChatEntryUserStatus
    }
}
.PerPage(page, perPage)
.ToListAsync();
```

Then this looks like you may be able to leverage those navigation properties something like:

```
var chatEntryDetails = await context.ChatEntries
    .Where(c => c.Chat.Id == chatId)
    .Select(c => new ChatEntryDetails
    {
        UserId = c.GroupMember.User.Id,
        GreetingName = c.GroupMember.User.GreetingName,
        GroupMemberId = c.GroupMember.Id,
        CreateDateTime = c.CreateDateTime,
        Details = c.Details,
        ChatType = c.ChatType, 
        DateReadByUser = c.ChatEntryUserStatuses
            .Max(s => s.CreateDateTime),
        ChatEntryId = c.Id,
        ReadByCount = c.ChatEntryUserStatuses.Count()
   }).Skip(pageCount * pageSize)
   .Take(pageSize)
   .ToListAsync();
```

Which is considerably simpler than sifting through joins. The two deviations that you may need to look at are the `ToApi()` modifier that was on the ChatType, and the `PerPage()` method which seems to provide pagination. Anything in the `Select` needs to ultimately boil down to SQL through EF, so there's a good chance that even without the original "count" join issue, that `ToApi()` would have triggered an exception. (Earlier EF Core versions would have pulled the query client-side when detecting something like that. It saves you from an exception but usually kills the performance and memory footprint for the query) If I had to guess I'd say this is translating a string or numeric value into another value suited to the consumer of this data. If that is the case where you want to translate values such as 1,2,3,4 to "A","B","C","D" then this can be a bit tricky. Inside the LINQ expression you can use (? :) I.e:

```
ChatType = c.ChatType == 1 ? "A" : c.ChatType == 2 ? "B" : c.ChatType == 3 ? "C" : c.ChatType == 4 ? "D" : "?"
```

which is rather messy. Instead, I would typically recommend populating ChatType as-is in the ViewModel (ChatEntryDetails) and add a translated ApiChatType property which does a `switch()` statement across ChatType to return the appropriate translation.

For pagination use the stock-standard Linq pagination methods of `Skip` and `Take` to ensure these are translated to the SQL query as well.  We can get the latest CreateDateTime from the user statuses using `Max`, though an `OrderByDescending` + `FirstOrDefault` + `Select` can work here as well. readByCount is provided by just asking for the `Count` of the related statuses.